# Javascript Replace All words

Tags: javascript, str-replace

I need to replace all the words in a DOM (web page in memory) using jquery and javascript.
I need to transform this:

```
<html>
<head>
    Hi to all
</head>
<body>
    Hi to all
</body>
</html>
```

Into this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        Bye to all
    </head>
    <body>
        Bye to all
    </body>
</html>
```

But without modifying the tags (ONLY THE VALUES IN THERE)

One try is:

```
jQuery.fn.replaceEachOne = function (objective, rep) {
    return this.each( function(){
                $(this).html( $(this).html().replace( new RegExp('(\\s'+objective+'\\s(?![[\\w\\s?&.\\/;#~%"=-]*>]))', "ig"), rep) );
            }
        );
}
```

But it continue replacing the tag values and breaks the page if I put it.

Help!!!

Comment: @itchy: Regarding point 2, jQuery is stated in the question.

Comment: @patrick dw: oops, missed that. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally...

Thanks to everyone...

```
jQuery.fn.replaceEachOne = function (objective, reposition) {
    this.contents().each(function(){
        if (this.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            $(this).replaceEachOne(objective, reposition);
        } else if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            var label = document.createElement("label");
            label.innerHTML = this.nodeValue.replace(objective, reposition);
            this.parentNode.insertBefore(label, this);
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing that there are going to be other elements in the header rather then just replacing everything with the new text. Try out something like this

```
$(function(){
  var element = $('body, head').find('*:contains("Hi to all")');
  element.html('Bye to all');
});
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work :(. Becouse the content may contain more than just "Hi to all".

Comment: grab the content var content = element.html(); then do a string replace content.replace('Hi', 'Bye');

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want it to change your tags, why do you modify the "html"and not just the text?

```
jQuery.fn.replaceEachOne = function (objective, rep) {
    return this.each( function(){
                $(this).text( $(this).text().replace( new RegExp('(\\s'+objective+'\\s(?![[\\w\\s?&.\\/;#~%"=-]*>]))', "ig"), rep) );
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: I doesn't work becouse it erase all the tags and put the text as text! The page apears like plain text!! or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: ..ok,i guess. haven't tested it

Answer (score 0):

One way that would do it albeit inefficiently would be:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace('Hi to all', 'Bye to all');
```

The 'Hi to all' in quotes can also be replaced with a regex if you want.

Comment: i don't understand right, can you explain me more please? What is document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]

Comment: @Daniel G. R. document.getElementsByTagName() returns an array of pointers to all the elements with the given tag name 'html.'  Since there is only one of them, only the first one ([0]) is taken and assigned to element.  element.innerHTML can then be used to get and set the HTML text inside of that tag; the second line uses the replace method on element.innerHTML and then assigns that to element.innerHTML.